# Render PDF from Aura Component on a Salesforce Site

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pdf

I need to render a pdf(editable) that has been provided when the customer clicks the link. The aura component is used on a Salesforce site.  What is the best option to make the pdf available? Can I use the pdf as a static resource and reference it?
Thanks,
P

Comment: Are you trying to render this "on-the-fly", or is it indeed a static form they are download?

Comment: It will be a static PDF form that the customer is supplying.  What I need to happen is the user will click the link(pdf file) which will open an editable PDF file where they will complete and then download.